# How can I remove the rearview mirror button off my windshield that I just put on upside down?

Tags: windshield

How can I get a rear view mirror button off the windshield if it was put on upside down?

Comment: Success now have to wait till it cools off Lol grrr but I did it lol

Answer (score 9):

Applying heat to one side, interior, of a vehicles windscreen runs the very real risk of cracking the windscreen, because of the differances in expansion. The more usual way to remove a stuck on mirror is too use a length of wire. Introduce the wire under one corner of the mirror and pull it side to side to cut through the adhesive and any patch used. Finish off by cleaning off any residue adhesive. This is the same method used by professional outfits to remove whole bonded windscreens when they are too be re-used. Using heat is is a very risky business unless you are able to control the temperature of the whole screen and should only be considered as alast resort.

Answer (score 4):

I found these instructions on [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_5246232_remove-adhesive-rear-mirror.html):

> 1. Use the blow dryer or heat gun to warm the mirror mount right where it attaches to the windshield. You are applying this heat to soften the adhesive underneath.
> 2. Test the mirror every so often while you are heating it by trying to gently move the mirror slightly back and forth. Once you feel movement, continue to apply heat and increase the force a little at a time. Work the mirror back and forth and it will release from the windshield, leaving a fair amount of adhesive behind.
> 3. Warm the adhesive left on the windshield again. For thick patches of adhesive, wrap the fishing line around your fingers as if you were getting ready to use dental floss and press your fingers up tight against the windshield on either side of the remaining adhesive. Work the line under the top edge, and move the line back and forth with downward pressure. The line will cut through the adhesive and remove all but a little residue.
> 4. Apply the adhesive remover to the residue and use the razor scraper to gently scrape off the rest of the adhesive. Wipe the area with a rag and more adhesive remover.
> 5. Clean the area with glass cleaner.

These look fairly comprehensive. You may want to put the mirror on the mount, even though it's upside down, so as to have something to hold on to. Do not apply too much force to it, though, as you run the risk of breaking it. Also, ensure you remove all of the glue off of the mount, as new glue will not want to stick to it if you don't.

Comment: This sort of answer seems common to all adhesive removal (except for the razor part).  Do we need an adhesive tag (or something like it)?

Answer (score 2):

They actually sell a debonding agent just for that very purpose. As I recall, it sprays on & wicks under the button, releasing the button.

But... the SIMPLE thing to do, and least worrisome, is to get another button and stick it directly to the one that's already in there... only right-side-up this time. Nobody will ever notice that you have two buttons, one stuck atop the other. I've watched a good mechanic do that in a Porsche dealership.

Comment: I tried doing the above - applying new button on top of one installed incorrectly, and it just fell right off when I put the mirror on. Maybe a temporary solution and it might work for longer than it did for me but park it in the sun on a hot day and it'll slide right off.

Comment: Did you clean the back of the previous button thoroughly before glueing the new one onto it? It (like the windshield) needs to be absolutely sparkly squeaky impeccably clean or it won't take glue right. I've seen double-button mirrors that lasted for years in off-roading trucks.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get mine off using floss. It fits into the gap between the windshield and the glued on metal button better than wire. You have to keep at it and use several pieces of floss since the floss will break. It took me about 10 minutes. Floss is thinner than most wires and fits into the narrow gap well.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the dental floss and it wanted to cut into my hand holding it taught. 
I then used a disposable lighter, paying attention to only letting the flame touch the metal mount part, with the mirror removed (I shattered a windshield once directing flame into the glass).
10 or 15 seconds, a couple times, and it popped right off with pliers!

Answer (score 1):

The wrench trick did it for me.  Carefully applied pressure with a long handled wrench and just when I thought it wasn't going to work-pop! No damage to the glass, either.  The hardest part was finding the button after it popped off.  It ended up under the passenger side seat almost under the rails.

Answer (score 1):

I attached a pair of vise-grips and then heated the button with a small-flamed disposable lighter for about 50 seconds. Moved the vise-grips sideways and the button slid right off. Very safe due to the small flame of the lighter.

Answer (score 1):

I put a razor blade in a pair of vise grips and slid the sharp edge of the blade across the wind shield striking the glue. After the 4th hit it flew right off.

Answer (score 1):

I just now  accidentally glued the button on upside down. Here's how I fixed it. I attached the mirror to the upsidedown  button and then pried it off. Then with a very flat screwdriver I scraped everything off the window and the button,  and used glass cleaner to clean both pieces.  I just glue the button back on right side up, fingers crossed it's sticks.

Answer (score 1):

Not having a heat gun, I held a candle flame to the button which kept the heat right in the middle. 30-45 seconds and grabbed the sides with pliers. came off easily and the glass was not hot.

Answer (score 1):

I took a single edge razor blade scraper and put it on the edge of the button and pushed.
Off it popped.
Cleaned the window from the glue with the scraper.
"Wallah....
I cleaned the window and used a repair kit to reattach the mirror.

Comment: Thanks Marylyn Sanders did the same as you with single edge razor scraper not much pressure by fourth tap it popped right off. thanks again. Steve